# Programa tendo saída inesperada

Tags: c++, c++11

Estou tendo um problema de saída inesperada e não consigo achar o erro em meu código, a saída em questão é os erros de todas as frases as quais não sejam "Cachorro anda .", uma observação notória é o fato de se o usuário entrar com "Cachorro" enter "anda" enter "." enter, o programa só vai acusar o NOT OK ao fim do ".", porém, quando colocamos quaisquer outras frases que não sejam as mesmas citadas, no primeiro enter já obtenho o resultado "Not ok". Ex: "Peixe" enter, (Not ok impresso), "Nada", enter, (not ok impresso), ".", enter, (not ok novamente).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> nome;
vector<string> verbo;     
vector<string> conjuncao;

void inicializar(){     // Função pra definir valores dos vetores  
nome.push_back("cachorro");
nome.push_back("passaro");
nome.push_back("peixe");

verbo.push_back("anda");
verbo.push_back("nada");
verbo.push_back("voa");

conjuncao.push_back("e");
conjuncao.push_back("ou");
conjuncao.push_back("mas");

}

bool isName(string v){
    for(int x = 0; x<nome.size(); x++){   //Verifica se a primeira palavra é um nome
       if(nome[x] == v) return true; 
       return false;
    }
}

bool isVerb(string v){
    for(int x = 0; x<verbo.size(); x++){
        if(verbo[x] == v) return true;  //Verifica se a segunda palavra é um verbo
         return false;
    }
}
bool isConjuncao(string v){
    for(int x = 0; x<conjuncao.size(); x++){
      if(conjuncao[x]==v) return true;   //Verifica se a segunda palavra é uma conj
      return false;
    }
}

bool sentenca(){  //Insere e faz todas as verificações

 string v;
 cin >> v;
 if(!isName(v)) return false;

 string v2;
 cin >> v2;
 if(!isVerb(v2)) return false;

 string v3;
 cin >> v3;
 if(v3 == ".") return true;  //Se for ".", termina, senão, continua.
 if(!isConjuncao(v3)) return false;

 return sentenca();

}



int main()
{
inicializar();

while(cin){  //Cria um loop para repetir o processo.
  bool b = sentenca();
    if(b) cout << "OK" << endl;  //Caso true, "ok"
    else cout << "Not ok" << endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Todos os três métodos de verificação estão errados.**

Você deveria colocar o "return false" fora do loop for e não dentro. Porque apenas se ele não encontrar lá dentro retornará falso.

**2) Sentença não deveria ser recursivo...**

Por qual motivo sentença é um método que chama a si mesmo? Você está fazendo o loop com o while já na função main. É melhor retornar falso se não encontrar um retorno verdadeiro.

Comment: Opa amigo, obrigado pela resposta. Em primeiro lugar, realmente, nem havia percebido as chaves (um erro realmente bobo hehe). Em segundo, ele chama a sí mesmo caso o v3 não tenha sido um ponto mas um "Mas", "e", "Ou", dando inicio a todo processo novamente. "Cachorro anda MAS peixe nada".